# Book about a man abducted by aliens and steals their ship

Tags: story-identification, aliens, spaceship, nanotechnology, alien-abduction

I read this a long time ago when I was young. I read it on my dad's kindle and have no idea what the title could be. 
I believe it was about a man that was abducted by an alien ship and woke up after being surgically worked on. He escaped the room and killed an alien goat-like thing. He then assumed control of the ship and I think there were nanobots involved. The ship could also create different things. That's all I remember, I just remember that young me thought it was a really cool book. It could have been 6-10 years ago, but the book itself could have been older.

Comment: Was it a short story or a novel? (Do remember if it was in a collection? Did you read it in one or two sittings, or closer to several weeks?)

Comment: It was a novel, and it took a few weeks to read. I don't know if it was a collection or not. I'm sorry, i know im not giving a lot of details

Comment: _I read this a long time ago when I was young. I read it on my dad's kindle_ this makes me feel excruciatingly old!

Comment: Kindle just celebrated its 10th anniversary (this week, in fact), so that puts a 10 year limit on this, if it was in fact an actual Kindle and not one of the few, very expensive book readers that preceded the Kindle.

Comment: This is quite a bit older than what is mentioned, but it has some elements in common with the Demu Trilogy by Busby.  In particular Cage a Man includes abuction by aliens, being surgically altered and stealing a ship to escape.  I don't recall nanobots, but as it was from the 1970s that concept was not widespread.  The abduction part unfortunately is a common trope so this may be hard to nail down.

Comment: I don't know if the kindle had a picture of the cover.  But the following has some additional info:   https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/f-m-busby/demu-trilogy.htm

Comment: I am also trying to find this (I guess) same book. I read it about 6-7 years ago. Nanobots were involved and if I remember correctly there was a boy and a girl and they got "enhanced" and took control of the ship, eventually they landed on moon.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure you are talking about the book
*[The Quantum Connection](http://www.baen.com/chapters/W200504/0743498968.htm?blurb)* (*Warp Speed* #2) 
by Travis S. Taylor

In the book, a man is abducted by an alien ship.  Like you say, he kills an alien, assumes control of the ship, and nanobot are definitely involved.  Before reading this book, though, you might want to read Warp Speed, the first book in the series.  The situations and many of the characters in *The Quantum Connection* come from the book *Warp Speed*.

Comment: That looks like a pretty good match. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the book you are looking for is ["Swarm (Star Force #1)" by B.V. Larson](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10101733-swarm). I was looking for this book also, and just happened to find the correct link.

> Earth arms marines with alien technology and builds its first battle fleet!
>
> Kyle Riggs is snatched by an alien spacecraft sometime after midnight. The ship is testing everyone it catches and murdering the weak. The good news is that Kyle keeps passing tests and staying alive. The bad news is the aliens who sent this ship are the nicest ones out there....

Comment: How and why does this match the OP's requirements? Can you please elaborate on this answer?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think this one actually matches up, but I pulled in the synopsis.